# NUnit setting Flag'd enum during TestCase

Tags: c#, .net, enums, nunit

I'm trying to get Nunit's TestCase to work with a Flag'd Enum:

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestCase(Framework.Environments.HD3 | Framework.Environments.BizTalk, "Test","Test")]
        public void SimpleTest(Framework.Environments environment, string org, string source)
        {
            environment = Framework.Environments.BizTalk| Framework.Environments.HI5;
            ....
```

The firstline in the test is to see if the value is set properly - it works.
The TestCase doesn't set the Enum though. It gets the HD3 and not the HIALUnSecured.

This is how my Enum is created:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum Environments
    {
        HD3 = 0,
        HD1 = 1 << 0,
        HD2 = 1 << 1,
        HD4 = 1 << 2,
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work? Yes I could use a 4th Variable, but I'm interested in finding out what's going on.

**Update**

On further investigation I found that Nunit might be the issue:

```
    [TestCase("test", "test")]
    public void test(string a, string b)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("===============" + a + b);
    }
```

Inside the method : a and b as null.

It's most likely something to do with my NUnit, i'll have to dig a bit.

**Update 2**
It seems TestDriven.NET was the culprit. It was not working as intended. I updated TestDriven and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you breakpoint and debug `environment` at the beginning of the unit test, what is its value?

Comment: The value is HD3 at the start, after that it sets it correctly. After doing some testing, it seems to set it to the first value in the enum.

Comment: `HD3 = 0` does not make sense when dealing with flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestDriven.NET was the culprit. Upgrading that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your flags declaration, assuming `HD3` is a flagable value.

```
public enum Environments
{
    None = 0,
    HD1 = 1 << 0, // 1
    HD2 = 1 << 1, // 2
    HD3 = 1 << 2, // 4  
    HD4 = 1 << 3, // 8

    // etc.
}
```

In your first example, `Framework.Environments.HD3 | Framework.Environments.BizTalk`, assuming `HD3` is zero, is equivalent to just writing `Framework.Environments.BizTalk` as anything OR'ed with zero is just the other operands value.

Here's a unit test to prove it works as I described.

```
[TestFixture]
class EnumFlagsTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(Environments.HD1 | Environments.HD3)]
    public void ShouldBeTrue(Environments input)
    {
        // arrange
        Environments expectedEnum = (Environments.HD1 | Environments.HD3);
        int expectedNumericalValue = 5;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedEnum, input);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedNumericalValue, (int)input);
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Environments
{
    None = 0,
    HD1 = 1 << 0, // 1
    HD2 = 1 << 1, // 2
    HD3 = 1 << 2, // 4  
    HD4 = 1 << 3, // 8

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: It's not how the enumeration is created, as it works in all other aspects of the system. It seems that NUnit is incapable of handling an enumeration in the TestCase

Comment: It works for me, I updated my answer to include the unit test I used.

Comment: It seems it's an issue with NUnit - all TestCase values I pass in are turning to null, which would make what I'm seeing make sense. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Seems the culprit was TestDriven.Net

Answer (score 2):

NUnit definitely does not pass in null to test cases: if it did, NUnit's own tests would fail and we would have heard about it from folks!

I suspect that you may be using something other than NUnit's own runners to execute the tests. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes - TestDriven was not compatible with the latest version of NUnit.